# Flutter: Progress dialog is not hiding

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using progress_dialog 1.2.0 package to show a progress dialog in my app, it is showing when I call `pr.show()` but not getting hidden when I call `pr.hide()`:

```
onTap: () async {
    pr.show();

    print('clicked custom category');
    print(categorylist[index].catName);
    print(categorylist[index].catId);

    // await getAllProductsInCategory(categorylist[index].catId);

    setState(() {
        catId = categorylist[index].catId;
        myinitlist.clear();
        myinitlist = List.from(productList);
        pr.hide();
    });
},
```

When I uncomment that `getAllProductsInCategory()` function it hides the dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with :

```
onTap: () async {
    pr.show();

    print('clicked custom category');
    print(categorylist[index].catName);
    print(categorylist[index].catId);

    setState(() {
      catId = categorylist[index].catId;
      myinitlist.clear();
      myinitlist = List.from(productList);

       Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
         pr.hide().whenComplete(() {
          print(pr.isShowing());
        });
       });
    });
 },
```

or :

```
onTap: () async {
    pr.show();

    print('clicked custom category');
    print(categorylist[index].catName);
    print(categorylist[index].catId);

   Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
    setState(() {
      catId = categorylist[index].catId;
      myinitlist.clear();
      myinitlist = List.from(productList);


         pr.hide().whenComplete(() {
          print(pr.isShowing());
        });
       });
    });
 },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. Can you tell me why its not working without the Future.delayed .

Comment: It is still not working on my side, so I had to use my own customized widget to show the progress.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `await` keyword when you are using async calls to start progressDialog & hide:

```
await progressDialog.show();
await progressDialog.hide();
```

**Example:**

Add the Package:

```
dependencies:
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4

import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
```

Create and initialize a `ProgressDialog` object inside the `build()` method passing context to it.
Initialize the `ProgressDialog` object:

```
final ProgressDialog pr = ProgressDialog(context);
```

By default it is a normal dialog to show some message, if you would like to use it to show percentage of progress done, specify the optional `type` parameter and specify if you want your dialog to dismiss when back button is pressed `isDismissible` parameter (Optional):

````
//For normal dialog
pr = ProgressDialog(context,type: ProgressDialogType.Normal, isDismissible: true/false, showLogs: true/false);
    
//For showing progress percentage
pr =  ProgressDialog(context,type: ProgressDialogType.Download, isDismissible: true/false, showLogs: true/false);
> Note: Please initialize the ```ProgressDialog```, where you have availability of the context
Style the progress dialog (Optional)
pr.style(
  message: 'Downloading file...',
  borderRadius: 10.0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  progressWidget: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  elevation: 10.0,
  insetAnimCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
  progress: 0.0,
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  maxProgress: 100.0,
  progressTextStyle: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.black, fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
  messageTextStyle: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)
  );
````

Note: You don't need to use all parameters, all of them are optional.

Showing the progress dialog:

```
await pr.show();
Dynamically update the content shown out there
pr.update(
  progress: 50.0,
  message: "Please wait...",
  progressWidget: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  maxProgress: 100.0,
  progressTextStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
  messageTextStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
  );
```

Dismissing the progress dialog:

```
pr.hide().then((isHidden) {
  print(isHidden);
});

// or
await pr.hide();
```

Navigating to next screens must be done after the completion of Future - `hide()`. See here for example.
Check if progress dialog is showing:

```
bool isProgressDialogShowing = pr.isShowing();
print(isProgressDialogShowing);
Use custom body
    pr = ProgressDialog(
      context,
      type: ProgressDialogType.Normal,
      isDismissible: true,
      /// your body here
      customBody: LinearProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blueAccent),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
```

For more details: https://flutterrepos.com/repo/fayaz07-progress_dialog-